# Custom message for ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, hibernate-validator

I am using ConstraintValidator implementation as given below for validating request object for a spring boot REST service

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyRequestValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface MyRequestValidation {

    String message() default "Mandatory fields missing";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class MyRequestValidator
            implements
                ConstraintValidator<MyRequestValidation, MyRequest>{
   @Override
    public void initialize(MyRequestValidation constraintAnnotation) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }
   @Override
    public boolean isValid(MyRequest myRequest, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
 //do some validation
     context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();    
     context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Id can contain only alphabets and digits")
    .addPropertyNode("id")
    .addConstraintViolation();
   }
}

//REST end point
public interface RestApi{
  @Produces(MediaType.XML)
  @Consumes(MediaType.XML)
  @POST
  MyResponse action(@MyRequestValidation MyRequest myRequest);
}

@Component
public class RestApiImpl implements RestApi {
..
}
```

This produces output as

```
[PARAMETER]
[myRequest.arg0.id]
[Id can contain only alphabets and digits]
```

Is there anyway to produce JSON or XML message (or based on the @Produces annotation on the REST end point). I am using Hibernate implementations of these interface ConstraintValidatorContext

Comment: You mean, you would want to return json/xml response in case of validation failure?

Comment: Yes @secretsuperstar My Rest end point is marked as producing XML. Response and the business validation errors (encapsulated inside objects with annnotated XmlElement fields) are getting transformed to XML except these java constraint validations

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can capture `ConstraintViolationException` when occurs by implementing a  `custom error handler` then you can add anything on your response and status as well.

1.- Simple way to change status when `ConstraintViolationException` is thrown.

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException exception,
        ServletWebRequest webRequest) throws IOException {
        webRequest.getResponse().sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

2.- Custom way to put the response when a `ConstraintViolationException` occurs.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomError> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        CustomError customError = new CustomError();
        customError.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        customError.setMessage(exception.getMessage());
        customError.addConstraintErrors(exception.getConstraintViolations());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(customError);
    }
}
```